# Launch map Intent with more than one location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I want to open the maps and show an array of locations (put a PIN on every one of them). I've read that you can open one location with this code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=22.99948365856307,72.60040283203125                                                      
    (Maninagar)");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new activity or fragment with [map view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start).
Then add your markers to that map.
Moreover, you can add listeners on every marker and open google map by click.

Comment: Hi Onix, yes I knew that but now Google maps is not free anymore. There's a trial but I would prefer this solution, if it is posible